# How to get Interval from two dates?

Tags: sql-server, validation, date, intervals, datediff

I'm trying to get the interval (year) from two dates using DATEDIFF, but it calculate the years only. 
for an example,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2005-01-03', '2006-01-01');
```

the result is 1, but the obtained results should be 0, because the date is still 01 January.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Do you care about accuracy of the result when leap years come into play?

Comment: not at all, so here's the problem, I want to do this query
`Select * From Employee 
where (DATEDIFF(DAY, HireDate, GETDATE())/365)%6=0 
AND (GETDATE() 
      BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -6, CAST(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), HireDate,121),1, 4, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)))AS DATETIME)) 
      AND DATEADD(Month, 6, CAST(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), HireDate,121),1, 4, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)))AS DATETIME)))`
Showing all employee that was 6 years or multiples AND 6 months before and after hiredate in this year. Is that possible?

Comment: The question in your comment is very different to the original question. I'd recommend to ask a new question. Explain clearly what is your problem. Show the query that you have and explain what you are trying to achieve. Provide some examples, few rows of sample data and what you expect as a result of the query. If you ask the question like this you'll get good answers very soon. At the moment it is impossible (for me) to understand your question in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2005-01-03', '2006-01-01')/365;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2005-01-03', '2006-01-01')/365)
```